# How does the Exarch's Fearsome Jurist ability work with Extended Bane?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, archetype, inquisitor

The text of Fearsome Jurist indicates that the ability functions as and replaces bane.  So I'm fairly certain that means an Exarch cannot extend bane with the feat, the text "function as" sort of throws me off. If it functions as bane, am I still considered as having a bane class feature?

Answer (score 2):

## An [exarch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/dwarf/exarch-inquisitor-dwarf) [inquisitor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor) has fearsome jurist but doesn't have [bane](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor#TOC-Bane-Su-)

When the ability fearsome jurist says that it *functions as* bane, it means the ability fearsome jurist includes things like this…

> This ability only functions while the inquisitor wields the weapon. If dropped or taken, the weapon resumes granting this ability if it is returned to the inquisitor before the duration expires. This ability lasts for a number of rounds per day equal to the inquisitor’s level. These rounds do not need to be consecutive.

…that are absent from the description of the ability fearsome jurist yet are part of the description of the ability bane.

### An [exarch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/dwarf/exarch-inquisitor-dwarf) can't meet a [bane](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor#TOC-Bane-Su-) prerequisite, but try to persuade the GM to make a house rule

Although the exarch archetype's supernatural ability fearsome jurist "functions as" the typical inquisitor's supernatural ability bane, the ability fearsome jurist also thoroughly and totally *replaces* the typical inquisitor's supernatural ability bane.

This means an exarch can't take, for example, the feat [Extended Bane](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/extended-bane) because the exarch's supernatural ability bane has been replaced by the supernatural ability fearsome jurist. However, changing Extended Bane to Extended Fearsome Jurist and letting the renamed feat function in exactly the same way except applying to the exarch's supernatural ability fearsome jurist instead of the inquisitor's supernatural ability bane is an *extremely* reasonable house rule.

Comment: Thanks again, Chan :) I had suspected as much but always like second opinions.